# How to pass column names in selectExpr through one or more string parameters in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using script for CDC Merge in spark streaming. I wish to pass column values in selectExpr through a parameter as column names for each table would change. When I pass the columns and struct field through a string variable, I am getting error as ==> mismatched input ',' expecting

Below is the piece of code I am trying to parameterize.

```
var filteredMicroBatchDF=microBatchOutputDF
.selectExpr("col1","col2","struct(offset,KAFKA_TS) as otherCols" )
.groupBy("col1","col2").agg(max("otherCols").as("latest"))
.selectExpr("col1","col2","latest.*")
```

Reference to the script I am trying to emulate: -
https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/merge-in-cdc.html

I have tried like below by passing column names in a variable and then reading in the selectExpr from these variables: -

```
val keyCols = "col1","col2"
val structCols = "struct(offset,KAFKA_TS) as otherCols" 

var filteredMicroBatchDF=microBatchOutputDF
.selectExpr(keyCols,structCols )
.groupBy(keyCols).agg(max("otherCols").as("latest"))
.selectExpr(keyCols,"latest.*")
```

When I run the script it gives me error as 
`org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException:`
`mismatched input ',' expecting <<EOF>>`

**EDIT**

Here is what I have tried after comments by Luis Miguel which works fine: -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, functions => sqlfun}

def foo(microBatchOutputDF: DataFrame)
       (keyCols: Seq[String], structCols: Seq[String]): DataFrame =
  microBatchOutputDF
    .selectExpr((keyCols ++ structCols) : _*)
    .groupBy(keyCols.head, keyCols.tail : _*).agg(sqlfun.max("otherCols").as("latest"))
    .selectExpr((keyCols :+ "latest.*") : _*)

var keyColumns = Seq("COL1","COL2")
var structColumns = "offset,Kafka_TS"

foo(microBatchOutputDF)(keyCols = Seq(keyColumns:_*), structColumns = Seq("struct("+structColumns+") as otherCols"))
```

**Note: *Below results in an error***

```
foo(microBatchOutputDF)(keyCols = Seq(keyColumns), structColumns = Seq("struct("+structColumns+") as otherCols"))
```

The thing about above working code is that, here keyColumns were hardcoded. So, I tried reading (firstly) from parameter file and (Secondly) from widget which resulted in error and it is here I am looking for advice and suggestions: -

**First Method**

```
def loadProperties(url: String):Properties = {
    val properties: Properties = new Properties()
    if (url != null) {
      val source = Source.fromURL(url)
      properties.load(source.bufferedReader())
    }
  return properties
}
var tableProp: Properties = new Properties()
tableProp = loadProperties("dbfs:/Configs/Databricks/Properties/table/Table.properties") 
var keyColumns = Seq(tableProp.getProperty("keyCols"))
var structColumns = tableProp.getProperty("structCols")
```

keyCols and StructCols are defined in parameter file as: -

`keyCols = Col1, Col2` *(I also tried assigning these as "Col1","Col2")*
`StructCols = offset,Kafka_TS`

Then finally,

```
foo(microBatchOutputDF)(keyCols = Seq(keyColumns:_*), structColumns = Seq("struct("+structColumns+") as otherCols"))
```

The code is throwing the error pointing at first comma (as if its taking the columns field as single argument):
`mismatched input ',' expecting <EOF>`
`== SQL ==`
`"COL1","COL2""`
`-----^^^`

If I pass just one column in the keyCols property, code is working fine.
E.g. `keyCols = Col1`

**Second Method**
Here I tried reading key columns from the widget and its the same error again.

```
dbutils.widgets.text("prmKeyCols", "","") 
val prmKeyCols = dbutils.widgets.get("prmKeyCols") 
var keyColumns = Seq(prmKeyCols)
```

The widget is passed in as below
`"Col1","Col2"`

Then finally,

```
foo(microBatchOutputDF)(keyCols = Seq(keyColumns:_*), structColumns = Seq("struct("+structColumns+") as otherCols"))
```

This is also giving same error.

Comment: Do `"struct(offset,KAFKA_TS) as otherCols"` before you call selectExpr. For ex, 'df.withColumn' first and select otuerCols column.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thank you for the suggestion. I have added details in my question.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am getting this message:
error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)

Comment: @SwapandeepSingh Both your config file and your widget return a **String**. If you need to turn a **String** of values _separated by comma_ into a **Seq**, you can just `val seq = str.split(',')`. Anyways, I would really recommend you to take any introductory course in **Scala**, here are many basic concepts that you are struggling with. Also, IMHO, **Spark** is a pretty complex technology to use if you lack so many fundamental concepts.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes thats what I was looking for. My issue is resolved. And yes, I am aware of the complex nature of the technology and currently taking courses alongside. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, functions => sqlfun}

def foo(microBatchOutputDF: DataFrame)
       (keyCols: Seq[String], structCols: Seq[String]): DataFrame =
  microBatchOutputDF
    .selectExpr((keyCols ++ structCols) : _*)
    .groupBy(keyCols.head, keyCols.tail : _*).agg(sqlfun.max("otherCols").as("latest"))
    .selectExpr((keyCols :+ "latest.*") : _*)
```

Which you can use like:

```
foo(microBatchOutputDF)(keyCols = Seq("col1", "col2"), structCols = Seq("struct(offset,KAFKA_TS) as otherCols"))
```

Comment: Thanks Luis. I implemented the above code but it still gives the same error.
error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
(such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
    .groupBy(keyCols : _*).agg(sqlfun.max("otherCols").as("latest"))

Comment: So, it managed to resolve this error but now it is back to the initial error message.
mismatched input ',' expecting <<EOF>>

I want to point here that when I am calling the foo function, I am passing parameters in keyCols and structCols field...which is what I want to achieve. So, I called the function like this: -
foo(microBatchOutputDF)(keyCols = Seq(keyCols), structCols = Seq(structCols)
and it fails.

If I call like how you mentioned, it works but it defeats the goal: 
foo(microBatchOutputDF)(keyCols = Seq("col1", "col2"), structCols = Seq("struct(offset,KAFKA_TS) as otherCols"))

Comment: @SwapabdeepSingh what you have in your snippet is not valid syntax, and will never be, no matter what you do. What I show you is how to pass many values, using a `Seq`. I do not see how that defeat the purpose.

Comment: so there is no way I can parameterize the column names in selectExpr? This is what my goal is. Since the column names would change for each table, and I want to pass them in my script after reading from properties file in dbfs depending on what table the script is running for.

Comment: @SwapandeepSingh yes you can, passign a `Seq` as I just showed.

Comment: but we are hardcoding Col1, Col2, offset and Kafka_TS columns when calling the foo function. I don't want that. When I do, I get the error. I understand I might not be getting what you are trying to say but this is where I am stuck.

Comment: @SwapandeepSingh but you can call the function with any value ._. And you can recieve those values for other function... like any other value. This is your first time using a function?

Comment: Hi @Luis, I have updated my post with the logic that I tried incorporating your code. Would you be able to take a look and advice if you have any suggestions. I am relatively inexperienced in Scala and trying to enhance the existing code.